# Needing assitance getting orders in last 2 quarters

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I am new to sql and need help with a problem. Can anyone please help?

For each customer with orders in the last two quarters of the previous year, display their total extended cost for each of the last two quarters of the previous year.
A quarter of a year is 3 months- the first quarter is months 1, 2, 3; the second quarter is months 4, 5, 6; the third quarter is months 7, 8, 9; the fourth quarter is months 10, 11, 12. The result set should display one row per customer; the first column is the customer id, the second is the total for quarter 3 and the third column is the total for quarter 4. Display 0 if there are no sales for that customer in that quarter.

```
Select cust_id
, ifnull(Quarter1, 0) as Quarter1
, ifnull(Quarter2, 0) as Quarter2
FROM a_bkorders.customers
a_bkorders.order_headers using (cust_id)
Join a_bkorders.order_details  using (order_id)
where order_id IN
(
     Select order_id
     FROM a_bkorders.order_details
        GROUP BY order_id
         Having QUARTER(orders)=
         (
           Select QUARTER(orders)=1 as Quarter1
                , QUARTER(orders)=2 as Quarter2
               From(    
                Select order_id 
                     , sum(order_price * quantity) as orders
                   FROM a_bkorders.order_details
                   )tbl
          )
 );
```

HERE ARE THE TABLES:

```
        -- create customers
        create  table  a_bkorders.customers (
            cust_id           integer          not null 
          , cust_name_last    varchar(20)      not null
          , cust_name_first   varchar(20)      null
          , cust_state        char(2)          not null
          , cust_postal_code  char(10)         not null
          , cust_acct_opened  date             not null 
          , constraint bk_cust_pk              primary key (cust_id)
          , constraint bk_cust_id_range        check (cust_id > 1000)
          , constraint bk_cust_acct_opened_ck  check (cust_acct_opened >=  '1975-01-01' )
        )engine = INNODB;


    -- create order_headers 
    create  table   a_bkorders.order_headers (
        order_id          integer          not null 
      , order_date        date             not null
      , cust_id           integer          not null 
      , constraint bk_orders_pk            primary key (order_id)
      , constraint bk_orders_cust_fk       foreign key(cust_id) 
                   references a_bkorders.customers(cust_id) 
      , constraint bk_order_id_range       check (order_id > 100)
     ,  constraint bk_order_date_ck        check (order_date >=  '2000-01-01')
    )engine = INNODB;


    -- create order_details  
    create  table   a_bkorders.order_details (
        order_id          integer          not null 
      , order_line        integer          not null 
      , book_id           integer          not null 
      , quantity          integer          not null 
      , order_price       numeric(6,2)     not null   
      , constraint bk_orderline_pk         primary key (order_id, order_line)
      , constraint bk_orderline_order_fk   foreign key (order_id) 
                   references a_bkorders.order_headers(order_id) on delete cascade
      , constraint bk_orderline_book_fk    foreign key (book_id )  
                   references a_bkinfo.books(book_id)
      , constraint bk_quantity_ck          check (quantity > 0) 
      , constraint bk_ordprice_ck          check (order_price >= 0) 
    )engine = INNODB;
```

HERE ARE SOME INSERTS:

```
    -- customers  
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (208950, 'Adams', 'Samuel',        'MA', '02106', '1996-04-15' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (200368, 'Blake', 'William',       'CA', '95959', '1997-07-15' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (258595, 'Jobs', 'Peter',          'MA', '02575', '1997-01-09' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (263119, 'Jones', null,            'IL', '62979', '1997-03-02' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (224038, 'Austin', 'Pat',          'CA', '95900', '1997-08-02' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (255919, 'Milton', 'John',         'NJ', '08235', '2011-05-31' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (211483, 'Carroll', 'Lewis',       'CA', '94203', '1998-08-08' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (221297, 'Dodgson', 'Charles',     'MI', '49327', '2001-05-06' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (261502, 'Hawthorne', 'Nathaniel', 'MA', '02297', '2001-10-12' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (212921, 'Books on Tap', NULL,     'CA', '94112', '2002-01-06' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (260368, 'Muller', 'Jonathan',     'IL', '62885', '2005-12-15' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (259969, 'Carlsen', 'Benny',       'NJ', '08505', '2011-07-12' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (239427, 'Marksa', 'Anna',         'NJ', '08495', '2011-02-28' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (296598, 'Collins', 'Douglas',     'MO', '65836', '2005-04-25' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (276381, 'Collins', 'Douglas',     'OH', '22451', '2005-02-08' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (234138, 'Keats', 'John',          'IL', '61500', '2006-04-30' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (267780, 'Shelly', 'Mary',         'CA', '94100', '2010-10-02' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (290298, 'Swift', 'Jonathan',      'MI', '49201', '2010-10-12' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (226656, 'Randall', 'Randell',     'NJ', '08251', '2011-08-08' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (222477, 'Rossetti', 'Christina',  'MI', '49742', '2011-07-11' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (227105, 'Kafka', 'Franz',         'MA', '02297', '2010-12-31' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (202958, 'Denver', null,           'IL', '60405', '2011-01-15' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (218709, 'Bonnard', 'Paul',        'MA', '02558', '2005-11-15' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (217796, 'Anders', null,           'IL', '62505', '2011-03-30' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (272787, 'Carlson', 'Ben',         'IL', '62505', '2011-05-05' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (234709, 'Brahms', 'Johnnie',      'MA', '02558', '2012-01-15' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (217002, 'Grieg', 'Edvard',        'IL', '62329', '2012-02-29' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (272611, 'Jarrett', 'Keith',       'IL', '62329', '2011-11-11' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (299099, 'Sam', 'Dave',            'CA', '94141', '2011-01-01' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (259906, 'Capybara', 'Wile E.',    'CA', '94132', '2012-01-05' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (259907, 'Hedge', 'Mr.',           'CA', '94132', '2011-09-05' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (282716, 'Biederbecke','Dwight',   'PA', '18106', '2013-01-01' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (287261, 'Biederbecke','Bix',      'PA', '18106', '2012-01-01' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (226275, 'Dalrymple','Jack',       'SD', '57216', '2013-01-01' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (228175, 'Cardin','Benjamin',      'MD', '20609', '2013-04-02' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (228275, 'Mikulski','Barbara',     'MD', '21203', '2013-04-04' );
    insert into a_bkorders.customers  values  (228352, 'Edwards','Donna',        'MD', '21205', '2013-06-08' );


-- orders and  order_details 
/* July 2011 */
Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(21841,  '2011-07-02', 267780);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21841, 1, 1448, 50,  25.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(21850,  '2011-07-02', 261502);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21850, 1, 1162,  1,  30.49);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21850, 2, 1109,  1,  25.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2045,  '2011-07-18', 267780);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2045, 1, 1894,  1,  35.99);   

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2200,  '2011-07-18', 261502);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2200, 1, 1200,  5,  16.33);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2200, 2, 1180,  5,  45.99);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2200, 3, 1128,  5,  46.20);


/* Sep 2011 */

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(22909,  '2011-09-25', 239427);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(22909, 1, 1104,  5,  45.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(22910,  '2011-09-25', 218709);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(22910, 1, 1678,  5,  49.99);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(22910, 2, 1162,  5,  35.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(32997,  '2011-09-22', 239427);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(32997, 1, 1948,  5,  40.94);  
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(32997, 2, 1199,  5,  18.39);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(32997, 3, 1457,  5,  53.99);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(32997, 4, 1133,  5,  18.15);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(32997, 5, 1894,  5,  36.79);


Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(32998,  '2011-09-22', 261502);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(32998, 1, 2006,  3,  20.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(41005,  '2011-09-28', 290298);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(41005, 1, 1142,  2,  42.45);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(41005, 2, 1107,  4,  21.50);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(41006,  '2011-09-28', 267780);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(41006, 1, 1142, 10, 42.95);  

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(42899,  '2011-09-29', 261502);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(42899, 1, 1128,  5, 25.00);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(42899, 2, 1103,  1 , 10.95);  

/* Oct 2011 */

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(21254,  '2011-10-23', 263119);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21254, 2, 2008,  10,   46.95);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21254, 3, 2007,  10,   39.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(21255,  '2011-10-28', 267780);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21255, 1, 1101,  5,    59.99);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21255, 2, 1142,  5,    39.00);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21255, 3, 1162,  2,    35.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(21261,  '2011-10-28', 200368);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21261, 1, 1142,  100,  34.95);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21261, 2, 1128,  50,   46.95);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(21261, 3, 2001,  100,  39.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(32905,  '2011-10-02', 259906);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(32905, 1, 2028,  1,  58.00);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, SUM(IF(QUARTER(od.orders) = 1, od.order_price * od.quantity, 0)) Quarter1, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(od.orders) = 2, od.order_price * od.quantity, 0)) Quarter2, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(od.orders) = 3, od.order_price * od.quantity, 0)) Quarter3, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(od.orders) = 4, od.order_price * od.quantity, 0)) Quarter4
FROM a_bkorders.customers c 
INNER JOIN a_bkorders.order_headers oh ON c.cust_id = oh.cust_id 
INNER JOIN a_bkorders.order_details od ON oh.order_id = od.order_id 
WHERE YEAR(od.orders) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1
GROUP BY c.cust_id
```

Comment: Thank You. Extremely quick and accurate answers. I appreciate your assistance. You are very prompt!

Comment: Can you assist me with another problem that I am having here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676913/needing-assistance-with-counting-the-most-different-books

Comment: I have one last problem that I have been stuck on. If you have time to take a look, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679247/trying-to-solve-query-with-multiple-choices-in-where-clause